# Fragment doesn't update values from other fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bundle, detach

I am quite new in android, my intention is to pass this values to a fragment that it is my current fragment. But I want to **update the fragment**, I have this data in a different fragment.

When I execute this my bundle goes to the fragment. It doesn't change even I can do setText in my textView without the app stops.

```
private void passToScreen(String title, String artist, String album, Long duration) {
        bundle.putString("songTitle",title);
        bundle.putString("songArtist", artist);
        bundle.putString("songAlbum", album);
        bundle.putString("durationSong", duration.toString());

        mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .detach(songScreen)
                .commitNowAllowingStateLoss();

        songScreen.setArguments(bundle);

        mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .attach(songScreen)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();

    })
```

What am I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: read this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: You can set data to your fragment directly without detach and attach this fragment.

Answer (score 0):

If the fragment is already visible, then you can get the instance of that fragment using the FragmentManager:

```
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_or_container_id);
myFragment.updateViews(bundle);
```

Then create the method in the fragment class to update the views:

```
public void updateViews(Bundle bundle) {
    //update the views
}
```

You don't need to detach the fragment.  Note that this will only work if the fragment is finished with the "commit" process.  The commit() and commitAllowingStateLoss() functions work asynchronously, so if you call findFragmentById() immediately after commit(), it will return null.

Answer (score 0):

Use interfaces to communicate between fragments
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html